# How to make irb quit after long idle?

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm a DBA, and I stumbled upon such case: developers run irb sessions (from Ruby on Rails app). This irb keeps database connection open. Sometimes - they forget about it, and it keeps on "running" - not doign anything, but still using one db connection.

I'd like to add some kind of "idle timeout" to their irb config. Is it possible? How to do it?

Comment: it might be better to kill the process after a certain time, because i don't think irb has a self-destruct option.  or maybe kill the process at 2am every morning or something?

Comment: 2am is very bad idea given that we have workers in at least 4 different time zones :) All working on the same machines :)

Comment: hm, yeah that's not gonna work then :)

Comment: You want to enforce this on the client, and timeout their irb sessions even if they're not connected to the DB?  Might it not be better to timeout idle db connections?  If it's Postgres, there are apparently things like PGBouncer that proxies the connection and manages idle ones, you could have devs configure their connection settings in the development environment to go through such a proxy/connection manager.

Comment: I know about pgbouncer, the problem is that I like idle db connections from app - i just don't like them from developers. even if they are using app credentials due to running migrations.

Comment: Only use the pgbouncer connection in development. The app can maintain a persistent connection in production, but whether they're doing it through the app or irb, dev connections will timeout. Is this not what you really want for your use case?

Comment: connections to database would time out only in certain (not all) cases. but the important thing is that as long as client is keeping connection open to pgbouncer - pgbouncer keeps it open (app <=> pgbouncer, not necessarily pgbouncer <=> db). And this is the problem, as it makes certain administratve jobs harder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick hack how you might implement this.

Note that this does not take into account that the user might be executing some long-running task inside the irb session. It simply looks at the time stamp of the last input; if it has not changed then it just flat out kills the process:

**Update**: it now checks if irb is currently running a command and ignores any timeouts if that is the case.

```
# Add some methods to IRB::Context and IRB::Irb
# for easier timeout implementation.
class IRB::Irb
  def status
    @signal_status
  end
end

class IRB::Context
  attr_reader :irb
  attr_reader :line_no

  def is_evaluating?
    self.irb.status == :IN_EVAL
  end
end

# Implement an auto exit timer thread. Timeout is given in seconds.
module IRB
  def self.auto_exit_after(timeout = 60)
    Thread.new {
      context    = IRB.conf[:MAIN_CONTEXT]
      last_input = Time.now
      last_line  = context.line_no

      loop {
        sleep 10

        # Check if irb is running a command
        if context.is_evaluating?
          # Reset the input time and ignore any timeouts
          last_input = Time.now
          next
        end

        # Check for new input
        if last_line != context.line_no
          # Got new input
          last_line  = context.line_no
          last_input = Time.now
          next
        end

        # No new input, check if idle time exceeded
        if Time.now - last_input > timeout    
          $stderr.puts "\n** IRB exiting due to idle timeout. Goodbye..."
          Process.kill("KILL", Process.pid)
        end
      }
    }
  end
end
```

To use it add the code to `.irbrc`, or some other place that auto-loads when irb is started, and then just start the timer:

```
IRB.auto_exit_after(60)
```

Comment: This works almost OK - but the almost is important. If I'll run some long-running command in the irb - long enough to be longer than timeout - it will get killed too. I know that users can modify the deadline, but if I was to trust users, I wouldn't have this problem in the first place. So the question is - can it be modified to **not** kill irb if there is a command running?

Comment: Missed the comment you made in the beginning about long running commands. Well - does it sound that what I want is not possible?

Comment: @user3095735 Nothing is impossible when you wield the power of programming in your hands :) The question here is how beautiful or reliable can we make it. It should be possible to do, but would have to spend more time investigating. If I get some spare time maybe I take a look. The irb source code is right there included with Ruby, it's just a matter of investigating how it works under the hood and see where you can hook into it (or find some other alternative method to detect running tasks).

Comment: Yeah - well, but I can't (realistically) do it myself, sorry - but I have almost none knowledge of Ruby.

Comment: Hmm ... tried it, changed "sleep 10" into "sleep 1" for faster debugging, then did: IRB.auto_exit_after(5), and immediately after - sleep 10. irb didn't exit after 5 seconds, it did let the sleep "work" for 10 seconds, but then it exited immediately after sleep finished, and not 5 seconds later.

Comment: Yep you found a bug. Added the patch here too.

Comment: For a Rails console, the IRB context isn't initialized immediately. I added a `sleep(5)` as the first line in the `Thread.new` to give it time to get initialized.